# Isolating y for functions in the form y + trig function (y) = x

Tags: calculus

I am a high school student currently taking Calculus BC. I am intrigued by a problem in which a base equation is given as:
$${2(x-y)}={3}+{cos(y)}$$
I have not found any method of isolating $y$, but it seems like there should be one, since the graph of the equation looks like a one-to-one function. Could someone let me know what this method is if it exists? If there is no such method, why is that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation feels relevant

Comment: Thank you for this. Transcendental equations seem like a very interesting feature of math.

Comment: There is a [Kepler equation series solution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation) which can be found via [Fourier series](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeries.html) for similar equations

Answer (score 0):

Your equation is a [transcendental equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation) because the cosine is a transcendental function.

If you have your unknown occur in different trigonometric functions there is sometimes a chance that you can combine these into a single one. For example $3\cos(x)=5\sin(x)$ might become $\tan(x)=\frac35$ and then $x=\arctan\left(\frac35\right)$. But with situations like in your example, where the unknown occurs both inside and outside trigonometric functions, that doesn't work.

So even though your function $x\mapsto y$ might be one to one (which I haven't verified), chances are very high that there is no [closed form expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) for that function. In terms of how to compute the function, that typically leaves your with numeric approximations. There is a lot of different [root-finding techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithms) you could employ.